# Invoke a Func object using reflection and a Type that's known at runtime

Tags: c#, casting, func

I've been trying to wrap my head around handling this scenario. The various similar (but not specifically the same) questions I've browsed on SO hasn't quite led me to where I'd like.

I have a situation where I have a `Type` and an object of type `Func<string, (bool, T)>` where T matches the `Type`. I'd like to be able to, via reflection or other means, call its `Invoke` method.

I have some `Type` at runtime:

```
Type type;
```

I have the `Func` in memory, but as an `object`:

```
object func;
```

The underlying Type of `func` is what I described earlier. For example, if `type` represents `DateTime`, then `func`'s underlying type would be:

```
Func<string, (bool, DateTime)>
```

But `type` can be anything at runtime, so if it was instead an `int`, then `func` would now be a

```
Func<string, (bool, int)>
```

How can I use the fact that I have the correct type at runtime, to invoke my func? I'm assuming I have to use reflection of some sort but don't really understand it well enough to get started.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm pretty new to reflection in general but I'm finding it very interesting and pretty difficult for some things. If you have any recommendations on readings or any other tips on how to better learn about reflection that'd be sweet as well!

**EDIT/UPDATE** after some more thought:

Would it be better just to use `dynamic` and call Invoke that way? Seems like it would work fine, but then that raises the question, of why you would ever go through the more difficult or longer process of setting up reflection to invoke something, instead of a simply dynamic call.

In any case, I'd still like to know how this would work using reflection, would be interesting to see

Comment: You'll have to use twice reflection, once to call the method and once (technically twice) to extract the values from the tuple. You could "cache" all this reflection by type, but it is unclear how you want to use `(bool, int)` (because you want to use it, right?). By using dynamic you can't "cache" the reflection, so each time you'll incur the whole cost of discovery and dynamic call. By using a `Tuple<>` instead of a `ValueTuple<>` you can skip reflection on the method call, because `Func<string, object>` will accept any `Func<string, Tuple<*>>`

Comment: Other solution would be to use a signature like `Action<string, out bool, out something>` (a little more complex, but it should be clear what I mean)... Now you'll need to use a single reflection to call the method. All these solutions are possible... But you must have an idea of which one you want.

Comment: The solution **I** would use would be to change the signature of the methods to `Func<string, (bool, object)>`. The methods to the boxing on the second return value. No reflection, simple code. In the end a method that returns a `(bool, TSomething)` is already something "custom", so I don't see any problem in changing it to `(bool, object)` to simplify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is wrong and "artificial". Yes, you can use reflection, yes, you can use dynamic... But the "right" thing to do would be to change the signature to:

```
public (bool, object) SomeMethod(string par)
```

delegate:

```
Func<string, (bool, object)>
```

or

```
public bool SomeMethod(string par, out object obj)
```

delegate (note that you can't use `Func<,>`/`Action<,>`):

```
public delegate bool MyDelegate(string par, out object obj)
```

With this signature you don't need reflection to call the method and you don't need reflection to parse the return. Your return value/`out` is boxed by the method inside the `object`. The performance is still better than using reflection.

Other semi-good candidate could be:

```
Tuple<bool, type> SomeMethod(string par)
```

(where `type` is your changing type)

delegate:

```
Func<string, object>
```

or

```
Func<string, dynamic>
```

By using a `Tuple<bool, type>` you gain something: `Tuple<>` is a reference type, and delegates are contravariant in the return type, so you can "unify" them to `object`/`dynamic` (`dynamic` is an `object` with some information to the C# compiler that the programmer will try to do "bad things" to the `object`)

Now you'll have to use reflection/`dynamic` to access the `Tuple<>.Item1` and `Tuple<>.Item2`.

The difference between using reflection and using `dynamic` is that by using reflection you can "cache" by `type` part of the reflection, so speeding up later uses of `type` methods, with `dynamic` this doesn't happen.

Comment: Looks like changing it to use `Func<string, (bool, object)>` makes the most sense. Oddly enough this was how I used to have it in the very beginning, but it felt weird to me then to have a type of object. I now realize that the other more recent stuff I've been trying relying on reflection and dynamic is even weirder. Thanks for the detailed responses/explanations, helped me understand it quite better!

Comment: hey xanatos, im stlil running into an issue where I can't quite get it to how I'd like. I have a concrete example up on github that I could show you. If you're wiling to take a quick peek send me an email to leesisaiah@gmail.com. I completely understand if not! btw, I don't want to post the link straight here since the value of it disappears in time, from a historical point of view. I expect the current code to be changed soon. Thanks!

Comment: @IsaiahLee sadly I can't... I don't have much free time (I'm going to vacation in a week or so, so I have to finish some things)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of your function like Func you can cast it directly as below

```
 private static void InvokeFunctionDynamically<T>(T data)
    {            

        //1. Define the delegate 
        Func<string, bool, T> genericFunction = (name, isEnabled) =>
        {
            if(isEnabled)
            {
                return data;
            }

            return default(T);
        };

        // 2. demonstrate that the delegate is retrieved at the run time as an object
        object runtimeObject = genericFunction;


        //3. Cast it directly to the delegate type
        var result =((Func<string, bool, T>) runtimeObject)("hello", true);

        Console.WriteLine($"Result {result}");
    }
```

The results are below:

[image]

Comment: Hey Toan, thanks for your reply. The Func signature I'm using is actually Func<string, (bool, T)> where the return type is a tuple

Comment: @IsaiahLee Is it a Tuple or a ValueTuple? Because your notation in the question is for ValueTuple.

Comment: @xanatos it's a ValueTuple, sorry for not being clear. In any case, the solution by Toan doesn't work because I don't know what T is during runtime. I know the type by an actual Type object